# SQL LOADER Control File without fields

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

I'm working on a task to load Database table from a flat file. My database table has 60 columns.
Now, In SQL LOADER control file, Is it mandatory to mention all the 60 fields ?
Is there a way to tell SQL LOADER that all 60 columns should be treated as required without mentioning the fields in the Control File ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734750/auto-match-fields-to-columns-sql-loader

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 12c (and higher versions) offer [express mode](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/learnmore/sqlldr-express-mode-wp-1991038.pdf).

In a few words (quoting the document):

> The SQL*Loader TABLE parameter triggers express mode. The value of the TABLE parameter is the name of the table that SQL*Loader will load. If TABLE is the only parameter specified, then SQL* loader will do the following:

> 1. Looks for a data file in the current directory with the same name as the table being loaded that has an extension of ".dat". The upper/lower case used in the name of the data file is the same as the case for the table name specified in the TABLE parameter
> 2. Assumes the order of the fields in the data file matches the order of the columns in the table
> 3. Assumes the fields are terminated by commas, but there is no enclosure character

> (...) order of the fields in the data file matches the order of the columns in the table. The following SQL*Loader command will load the table from the data file.

> `sqlldr userid=scott table=emp`

> Notice that no control file is used. After executing the SQL*Loader command, a SELECT from the table will return (...)

---

I guess that's what you're after.

Comment: Hi. Firstly My apologies for the delay in response to your answer. Yes. I am after this only. I will try this and get back to you. Many thanks